# Glob only returning first file in folder

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract all .txt files in a folder using Glob, when I run the below code on it's own, it returns all files:

```
import os
for f in os.listdir(folder):
    if f.endswith('.txt'):
       #Do Something
```

However, when I add this into a function and call it only the first .txt file in the folder is returned. I can't figure out why, can anyone help?

```
def read_files(path):
    list = []
    import os
    for f in os.listdir(folder):
        if f.endswith('.txt'):
           list.append(os.path.join(folder, f))
           return list
```

Comment: `return list` takes the execution out of method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you return from your function immediately after processing your first file. You need to dedent `return list` to be outside of the for loop.